# log screen doesn't show up. blank page instead

Tags: vaadin

my Vaadin 8 program starts without problems, but I got following error:

https://localhost:8180/VAADIN/static/client/client-4C23589935A74206212F474A719FC41C.cache.js not found. https://locahost:8180/login shows blank page

Did someone know what happened and how to fix it?

manually ran vaadinBuildFrontend and vaadinPrepareFrontend, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Please stop creating duplicates. Fix your first question (add your error
to the question instead of the comments).